# writing the present url to external page

Tags: php, fopen

It's pretty self-explanatory what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to write to a txt file the present page. Unfortunately, the txt file is blank.

```
    <?php 

function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

?>
<?php


$var_str = var_export($pageURL, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$$pageURL = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('kylie.txt', $var);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not calling the function to get the url:

```
<?php


function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .=     $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$pageURL = curPageURL(); // Added this line to pick up the current url
$var_str = var_export($pageURL, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$$pageURL = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('kylie.txt', $var);

?>
```